# How is that a binary tree with n! leaves has height omega (n log n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, depth

I came across this proposition that a binary tree with `n!` leaves has height `omega(n log n)`.
I am unable to understand how it is possible. I understand that height of a binary tree with `n` nodes is `log n <= h <=  n`,  i.e the height is at least `log n` (in case of `complete binary tree`), but I do not see a hint as to how the above proposition could be true or proved correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already stated that the lower bound for a binary tree with n nodes is log n. It is a well known fact (Stirlings formula), that log(n!) is approximately n log n. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for a derivation.

A tree with n! leaves and minimal height has approximately 2n! nodes. This gives log(2n!) = log 2 + log(n!) approximately log 2 + n log n which is in omega(n log n)

Comment: did not know about Stirlings Formula. will look at it. but n! leaves would mean more than n! nodes, how can you substitute than in log(n)?

Comment: m leaves means up to 2m-1 nodes.

Comment: @LiorKogan: how about n! leaves?

Comment: That would be up to 2(n!)-1 nodes of course, which is O(n!) nodes